# What's causing the paint event in this CSS animation?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building an animated menu based off of [Smooth as Butter: Achieving 60 FPS Animations with CSS3](https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108).

The canonical demo which I'm comparing my code against is: http://codepen.io/Onyros/pen/jAJxkW

This is my demo code:

```js
var navLayer = document.querySelector('.nav-layer'),
    open = document.querySelector('.open'),
    close = document.querySelector('.close');

function toggleNav() {
  navLayer.classList.add('nav-layer__animating');
  if (navLayer.classList.contains('nav-layer__visible')) {
    navLayer.classList.remove('nav-layer__visible');
  } else {
    navLayer.classList.add('nav-layer__visible');
  }
}

open.addEventListener('click', toggleNav, false);

close.addEventListener('click', toggleNav, false);

navLayer.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
  navLayer.classList.remove('nav-layer__animating');
}, false);
```

```css
.nav-layer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.nav-layer__visible {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: beige;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 1;
}
.nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 90vw;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: translateX(-91vw);
  will-change: transform;
}
.nav-layer__animating .nav {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in;
}
.nav-layer__visible.nav-layer__animating .nav {
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
.nav-layer__visible .nav {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-layer">
  <nav class="nav">
    <button class="close">Close</button>
  </nav>
</div>

<header class="header"><button class="open">Menu</button></header>

<article>
  <p>O hai</p>
</article>
```

When I run the canonical demo with paint flashing enabled in Chrome DevTools, I don't see any paint events.

[image: their demo]

When I run my demo, I see a flash of paint when I close the menu.

[image: my demo]

The event log in DevTools shows that there was a paint on `#document` and another on `nav.nav`.

The answer I'm looking for here is: find the CSS property in the canonical demo which is preventing this flash of paint. Or, maybe the difference is in how I've structured my HTML. I think the JS is equivalent, so it's unlikely to be there.

Please provide your methodology, too!

Comment: Looks like `.nav-layer__visible {
                  pointer-events: auto;
                  }` is causing the paint.

Comment: And I would use `transform` in your transition instead of `all` unless you have a reason to use `all`.

Comment: @MichaelCoker that does appear to solve it. However, why isn't this causing a paint flash in the canonical demo? Because it seems to use `pointer-events: auto` in the same way.

Comment: What's a canonical demo?

Comment: The canonical demo was the demo that I was basing my work off of. It's in the link at the top of my question. http://codepen.io/Onyros/pen/jAJxkW